# XMLHttpRequest to another subdomain with cookie persistence?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, xmlhttprequest

I am using XMLHttpRequest to submit data from a form on one subdomain to another. The code below is an example. However when doing so the PHP code in the page being requested notices that no cookie was set even if multiple requests were made. The PHP code thus needs to create a new cookie for each request. How is is possible for the cookie to persist in the target subdomain if multiple requests are made?

It will be difficult for me to change the cookie/session settings from the calling subdomain.

```
var url = "https://www.example.com/page.php?param=value"
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false ); 
xmlHttp.send( null );
```

Comment: For cross origin requests you need to set [XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials)

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks. This setting would send the credentials to the target domain. What I want is for the target domain to use its own cookie but not create a new one each time.

Comment: You can't control how a remote domain manages cookies and shouldn't need to be concerned about it either so long as you are sending valid ones

Comment: @charlietfl actually your solution was correct. I just had to set the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true on the target domain. Thanks.

Comment: Note that fetch() API supersedes XMLHttpRequest and is cleaner and more robust to use